# column-count on fieldset doesn't work for firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to do a multi-column layout for a form with multiple pairs of label and input. It works fine in Chrome and IE, but I can't get it to work with Firefox. ([demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/6CmJb/2/)).  I tried removing the `clear: left` on the `label`, but that doesn't help.

Here's the simplified HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <input type="number" value="0" />
    <label>Label 2</label>
    <input type="number" value="0" />
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
fieldset {
    height: 110px;      
    border: none;

    column-count: 2;        
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;    
}

label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
}

input {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 3px 0 3px 10px;
}
```

I also tried using `columns` and no luck.  Is there rules that I didn't add that is required for Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported on bugzilla already, oddly you can't use `column-count` with the `<fieldset>` element - take a look at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727164

If you replace the `<fieldset>` with a `<div>` or any other element it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/6CmJb/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be looking into the bug database next time around. :)