# CSS column-count in list inside fieldset doesn't break-word

Tags: css, google-chrome, column-count

column-list works fine fieldset, just not the word-wrap.

```
<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
        <li>bbbbbb</li>
        <li>ccccccc</li>
        <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a>aaaaaaaa</li>
        <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
        <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>

ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

ul li{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/jbe07sbs/1/

Tested in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m

Related: [column-count on fieldset doesn't work for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265815/column-count-on-fieldset-doesnt-work-for-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jbe07sbs/2/

```
ul li {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all; /** adding this will fix **/
}
```

> **Word-break: break-all**
>
> irrespective of whether it’s a continuous word or many words, breaks
>   them up at the edge of the width limit. (i.e. even within the
>   characters of the same word)

Comment: Cool, first I've heard of `word-break` [and the `break-all` value is well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know `break-all`